# Array<Vector2> How to define it?

Tags: java, arrays

I have to use method:

```
intersector.isPointInPolygon(Array<Vector2> polygon, Vector2 point);
```

And how should I define this Array?

`Vector2[]` doesn't work and display: [image: screen of error]

ArrayList too.

I tried with `Array<Vector2> poly`
and but i don't know how to add values into

[image: screen of me trying to fill array]
This way filling array doesn't work

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: How is the class `Array` defined? Can you show it?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, problem solved.
I wrote `Array<Vector2> poly;`
instead of `Array<Vector2> poly = new Array<Vector>();`
And occured NullPointerException.

Anyways thanks guys;